# Google Search Console: is it possible to get a list of de-indexed pages?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have noticed a decrease of my "Indexed pages" in the last few weeks while taking a look at the graph in my Google Search Console.

This surprises me because I did not make any significative change in my web recently, so I would like to know if it is possible to get a list of the disappeared pages to examine further.

Right now in my Google Search Console I can only see the currently indexed pages (which are less than a few weeks ago).

Is there a way to get a list of the indexed pages from for example, one month ago? A list of disappeared pages would be fine too.

Comment: Have you checked pages available in Page indexing->Crawled - currently not indexed?

These might be some issue due to which Google might not be indexing some of the pages. Some possible reasons can be:
1- No content on the pages
2- Temporary/permanent redirection observed by crawler for these pages
3- Soft 404 issues

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this issue before on some of my sites and the best answer I have been able to come up with is to integrate with the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/about). From there you could scrape your sitemap in order to query the API and determine which URLs have undesirable statuses such as *crawled currently not indexed* or *discovered currently not indexed*.  For me, this was more trouble than it was worth to get that information, but you're welcome to take a stab at building an app that would facilitate this sort of information gathering.

Answer (score 1):

Google search console does not provide a comparison of pages indexed now to the pages indexed one month ago.  The best you can do is look through the current data in the [Page Indexing report](https://search.google.com/search-console/index) and see if there is a reason that pages aren't indexed. The report is listed in the navigation as "Pages" in the "Indexing" category.

Google has about a dozen reasons that pages might not be indexed, and the report will start by showing you a list of reasons along with how many pages are not indexed because of that reason.

From there you can click on any of the reasons to see the list of URLs.

#### Screenshots:

[image: Page Indexing report from Google Search Console]

[image: Crawled - Not Currently Indexed report from Google Search Console]